# PHP: Include an SQL query containing $variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I really dislike writing SQL queries within my PHP.

Given the following example piece of PHP:

**script.php**

```
$name = 'Bill'
$query = "SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE name='$name'";
```

I'd like to instead write the sql query in it's own file and include (or otherwise) get the contents into my script:

**query.sql**

```
SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE name='$name'
```

**script.php**

```
// This doesn't work obviously
$query = '"'.include('query.sql').'"';
```

Note that I'd like to be able to reference PHP variables within the SQL query (e.g: $name is setup declared in script.php but used as part of the query).

Comment: Watch out for SQL injection when writing such queries. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: @Pierre-LoupPagniez thanks for that link. In my case all user input was being cleaned separately before being used in queries, but the attached question/answer is fantastic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nice and simple solution:

```
 $sql = file_get_contents("query.sql");
```

And to reference variables, I suggest using PDO where you reference like this

```
$query = $db->query( "SELECT x FROM x WHERE x = :example")
$query->execute(array("example"=>$value));
```

...But you can do something similar to this in mysqli, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**query.sql:**

```
SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE name=:name
```

**script.php:**

```
$query = file_get_contents('path/to/query.sql');
```

Then bind the parameters and execute the query.

See [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) for why you should bind variables instead of concatenating them into your query string.